# WhatsApp API Call Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'd like to execute the following call in rails:

```rb
curl -i -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "TO_PHONE_NUMBER", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "hello_world", "language": { "code": "en_US" } } }'
```

How can I do this using an http-client? I can do it in postman but formatting it for an http client usually has some syntax issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), which helps make API-call easier.